# Function to use table across multiple variables in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, openxlsx

I want to get the number of people who answered each question of my survey and export the results to an Excel file. Ideally, the respondent's frequency for each question would be saved in a new sheet. I was thinking the easiest way to do this is to build a function but perhaps a "simple" across would work?

Below is a general idea of what I think could work:

```
Variable_names <- dplyr::pull(liste_var, Var_name)

statdes <- createWorkbook()
  
fstatdes_2 <- function(base, l_var) {
  
  for (i in l_var){

des_[i] <- as.data.frame(table(base[[i]], useNA = "always"))

addWorksheet(statdes, sheetName = as.character(i))    

writeData(statdes,
          as.character(i),
          des_[i],
          startRow = 1,
          colNames = TRUE,
          withFilter = TRUE)

  }
}

stat_des = fstatdes_2(test, Variable_names)
```

Here is the data set:

```
structure(list(Q1 = c(3, 4, 3, 1, NA, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3), Q1a = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Q2 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1), Q3 = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), Q4 = c(1975, 1979, 
1974, 1975, 1978, 1965, 1984, 1991, 1966, 1969), Q5 = c(6, 4, 
19, 20, 18, 13, 13, 5, 38, 30), Q6 = c(5, 3, 1, 10, 2, 4, 4, 
2, 25, 6), Q7 = c(6, 3, 1, 17, 1, 2, 1, 5, 32, 7), Q8 = c(1, 
1, NA, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), Q9 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), Q10 = c(4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4), Q11 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), Q12 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Q13 = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Q14 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1), Q15 = c(5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5), Q15_other_ = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), Q16a = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), 
    Q16b = c(NA, NA, 14, 9, 16, 18, 19, 11, NA, 11), Q16c = c(NA, 
    NA, 26, 29, 32, 25, 25, 24, NA, 26), Q16d = c(NA, NA, 2, 
    2, 1, 2, 2, 1, NA, 1), Q17 = c(31, 28, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 28, NA), Q18 = c(1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3), Q19 = c(1, 
    1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1), Q20 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 1), Q21 = c(2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2), Q22_1_ = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, NA, 2, 2), Q22_2_ = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
    1, NA, 2, 2), Q22_3_ = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2), Q22_4_ = c(1, 
    1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, NA, 1, 2), Q22_5_ = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
    1, 1, 2, 2), Q22_6_ = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2), Q23_1_ = c(4, 
    4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), Q23_2_ = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 
    1, 2, 1, 1), Q23_3_ = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Q23bis_1_ = c(NA, 
    NA, 1, NA, 4, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), Q23bis_2_ = c(NA, NA, 1, 
    NA, 4, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), Q23bis_3_ = c(NA, NA, 2, NA, 1, 
    NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), Q23bis_4_ = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
    2, NA, NA), Q23bis_5_ = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, 
    NA), Q23bis_6_ = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, 4, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA), 
    Q24_1_ = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Q24_2_ = c(1, 2, 
    1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), Q24_3_ = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 
    3, 2, 1), Q24_4_ = c(1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1), Q24_5_ = c(1, 
    1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), Q24_6_ = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 2, 1), Q24_7_ = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Q24_8_ = c(1, 
    1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1), Q24_9_ = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 
    1, 2, 1, 1), Q24_10_ = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, NA, 1, 3, 2, 1), 
    Q24_11_ = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1), Q25 = c(2, 3, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1), Q26 = c(4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 6, 
    5, 4), Q27 = c(6, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 6, 8, 8, 5), Q28_1_ = c(4, 
    4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3), Q28_2_ = c(5, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4, 
    4, 1, 1, 4), Q28_3_ = c(4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 4), Q28_4_ = c(2, 
    5, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1), Q29 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
    2, 1, 1), Q29bis_1_ = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 2, 1
    ), Q29bis_2_ = c(3, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 3, 3), Q29bis_3_ = c(2, 
    3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1), Q30_1_ = c(4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 
    2, 1, 1, 4, 1), Q30_2_ = c(4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2), 
    Q30_3_ = c(4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3), Q30_4_ = c(3, 2, 
    3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3), Q30_5_ = c(4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 2, 3), Q30_6_ = c(3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Q30_7_ = c(2, 
    4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3), Q30_8_ = c(3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 1, 3, 3), Q30_9_ = c(4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2), Q30_10_ = c(1, 
    1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2), Q30_11_ = c(3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 
    4, 3, 3, 3), Q30_12_ = c(3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), Q30_13_ = c(3, 
    4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3), Q30_14_ = c(4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 
    4, 3, 3, 3), Q30_15_ = c(3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3), Q31_1_ = c(4, 
    2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4), Q31_2_ = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 2, NA, 
    4, 3, 2, 3), Q31_3_ = c(2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2), Q31_4_ = c(1, 
    2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), Q31_5_ = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 
    2, 3, 2, 3), Q31_6_ = c(1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2), Q31_7_ = c(2, 
    3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2), Q31_8_ = c(3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 
    3, 2, 3, 2), Q32_1_ = c(3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2), Q32_2_ = c(4, 
    2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2), Q32_3_ = c(4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 
    3, 3, 2, 1), Q32_4_ = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2), Q32_5_ = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2), Q32_6_ = c(3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 2), Q32_7_ = c(3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2), Q32_8_ = c(3, 
    2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2), Q33_1_ = c(3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
    4, 3, 2, 3), Q33_2_ = c(2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3), Q33_3_ = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3), Q33_4_ = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 1), Q33_5_ = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2), Q33_6_ = c(2, 
    2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2), Q34_1_ = c(4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 
    2, 1, 3, 2), Q34_2_ = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2), Q34_3_ = c(2, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), Q34_4_ = c(2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
    4, 4, 2, 4), Q35_1_ = c(4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3), Q35_2_ = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3), Q35_3_ = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 1), Q35_4_ = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1), Q37_1_ = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2), Q37_2_ = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 
    2, 3, 3, 4), Q37_3_ = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4), Q37_4_ = c(1, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3), Q37_5_ = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 
    2, 3, 4, 3), Q37_6_ = c(2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3), Q37_7_ = c(1, 
    3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2), Q37_8_ = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 
    3, 2, 3, 2), Q38_1_ = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4), Q38_2_ = c(3, 
    3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4), Q38_3_ = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
    4, 3, 2, 4), Q38_4_ = c(1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1), Q38_5_ = c(2, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3), Q38_6_ = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
    4, 4, 3, 2), Q39_1_ = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Q39_2_ = c(1, 
    2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2), Q39_3_ = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 
    3, 2, 2, 2), Q39_4_ = c(2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3), Q39_5_ = c(4, 
    2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), Q40_1_ = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
    2, 2, 3, 3), Q40_2_ = c(3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4), Q40_3_ = c(2, 
    2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2), Q40_4_ = c(3, 3, 3, 3, NA, 4, 
    3, 2, 2, 3), Q40_5_ = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2), Q40_6_ = c(3, 
    2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3), Q41_1_ = c(1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 
    2, 2, 3, 1), Q41_2_ = c(2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3), Q41_3_ = c(2, 
    3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4), Q41_4_ = c(3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 
    1, 2, 3, 4), Q42_1_ = c(1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2), Q42_2_ = c(3, 
    2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2), Q42_3_ = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 
    3, 2, 2, 1), Q42_4_ = c(2, 3, 2, NA, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4), Q42_5_ = c(1, 
    1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4), Q42_6_ = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 
    3, 2, 2, 1), Q42_7_ = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3), Q42_8_ = c(2, 
    4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3), Q42_9_ = c(2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 
    1, 2, 2, 3), Q42_10_ = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2), Q43_1_ = c(1, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2), Q43_2_ = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    4, 2, 3, 4), Q43_3_ = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4), Q43_4_ = c(3, 
    2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3), Q43_5_ = c(3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 
    2, 1, 1, 1), Q43_6_ = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2), Q43_7_ = c(2, 
    3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Q43_8_ = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
    1, 2, 2, 2), Q43_9_ = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), Q43_10_ = c(3, 
    2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2), Q43_11_ = c(3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 
    1, 3, 2, 2), Q44_1_ = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2), Q44_2_ = c(3, 
    3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4), Q44_3_ = c(1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
    3, 2, 2, 2), Q45 = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2), Q46 = c(2, 
    3, 2, 3, 4, NA, 3, 3, 3, 3), Q47 = c(2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 
    3, 2, 2), Q47bis_1_ = c(4, 4, NA, 3, NA, NA, 4, NA, 3, 4), 
    Q47bis_2_ = c(3, 4, NA, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, 3, 4), Q47bis_3_ = c(3, 
    2, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, NA, 2, 2), Q47bis_4_ = c(3, 2, NA, 2, 
    NA, NA, 1, NA, 2, 2), Q48 = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 
    2), Q49 = c(2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3), Q50 = c(3, 3, 
    4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3), Q50bis_1_ = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
    NA, 4, NA, 1, NA), Q50bis_2_ = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, 
    NA, 1, NA), Q50bis_3_ = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, NA, 2, 
    NA), Q50bis_4_ = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, 3, NA, 3, NA), 
    Q51_1_ = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, NA, 1, 3, 2, 4), Q51_2_ = c(2, 
    2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3), Q51_3_ = c(2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 
    4, 3, 4, 4), Q51_4_ = c(2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), Q51_5_ = c(3, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3), Q51_6_ = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
    4, 3, 2, 3), Q52_1_ = c(3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Q52_2_ = c(3, 
    2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4), Q52_3_ = c(3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 
    3, 3, 2, 2), Q52_4_ = c(3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Q52_5_ = c(1, 
    1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1), Q52_6_ = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
    2, 2, 2, 2), Q52_7_ = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3), Q52_8_ = c(2, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2), Q52_9_ = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
    1, 2, 1, 2), Q53_1_ = c(3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4), Q53_2_ = c(2, 
    2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), Q53_3_ = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
    3, 2, 3, 3), Q53_4_ = c(2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1), Q53_5_ = c(3, 
    2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1), Q53_6_ = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 
    2, 2, 2, 3), Q53_7_ = c(2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), Q53_8_ = c(2, 
    2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4), Q54_1_ = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 
    3, 3, 4, 1), Q54_2_ = c(1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1), Q54_3_ = c(3, 
    4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4), Q55_1_ = c(2, 3, 2, NA, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 2, 3), Q55_2_ = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2), Q55_3_ = c(3, 
    2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2), Q56_1_ = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
    4, 3, 1, 4), Q56_2_ = c(3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2), Q56_3_ = c(1, 
    2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), Q56_4_ = c(4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
    3, 3, 2, 3), Q56_5_ = c(3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1), Q58_1_ = c(2, 
    3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2), Q58_2_ = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 2), Q58_3_ = c(4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), Q58_4_ = c(3, 
    2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4), Q59_1_ = c(2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 
    2, 3, 2, 4), Q59_2_ = c(3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2), Q59_3_ = c(3, 
    3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4), Q59_4_ = c(2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
    2, 3, 2, 3), Q59_5_ = c(3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3), Q60_1_ = c(3, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4), Q60_2_ = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 1, 4), Q60_3_ = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3), Q60_4_ = c(3, 
    3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3), Q61_1_ = c(4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
    4, 2, 3, 2), Q61_2_ = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4), Q61_3_ = c(1, 
    3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4), Q62_1_ = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 
    1, 1, 3, 1), Q62_2_ = c(2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), Q62_3_ = c(1, 
    3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4), Q62_4_ = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 2, 3), Q62_5_ = c(2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4), Q63_1_ = c(3, 
    3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4), Q63_2_ = c(4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
    4, 2, 2, 4), Q63_3_ = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1), Q64_1_ = c(1, 
    1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Q64_2_ = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 1), Q64_3_ = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4), Q64_4_ = c(1, 
    2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2), Q64_5_ = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
    2, 3, 2, 2), Q65_1_ = c(3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, NA, 3, 3, 4), Q65_2_ = c(2, 
    2, 3, 2, 4, 2, NA, 2, 2, 3), Q65_3_ = c(4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 
    NA, 3, 2, 3), Q65_4_ = c(3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4), Q66_1_ = c(3, 
    1, 2, 3, 2, 2, NA, 2, 4, 4), Q66_2_ = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
    NA, 2, 2, 1), Q66_3_ = c(3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, NA, 2, 2, 3), 
    Q66_4_ = c(4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3), Q67_1_ = c(2, 2, 
    1, 2, 1, 2, NA, 1, 2, 1), Q67_2_ = c(3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 
    3, 2, 1), Q67_3_ = c(1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4), Q68_1_ = c(2, 
    2, 1, 1, 4, 1, NA, 1, 1, 2), Q68_2_ = c(1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
    NA, 2, 1, 1), Q68_3_ = c(2, 3, 1, NA, 3, 1, NA, 2, 1, 1), 
    Q68_4_ = c(3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3), Q68_5_ = c(3, 2, 
    3, 4, 3, 3, NA, 2, 3, 3), Q69_1_ = c(2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, NA, 
    2, 2, 1), Q69_2_ = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1), Q69_3_ = c(3, 
    2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3), Q69_4_ = c(4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
    NA, 1, 2, 2), Q69_5_ = c(1, NA, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1), 
    Q69_6_ = c(3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Q70_1_ = c(3, 3, 
    2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3), Q70_2_ = c(3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 
    2, 2, 4), Q70_3_ = c(2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, NA, 4, 2, 3), Q71_1_ = c(3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA, 3, 2, 4), Q71_2_ = c(3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
    NA, 3, 2, 1), Q71_3_ = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1), Q72_1_ = c(1, 
    1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 4), Q72_2_ = c(3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 
    NA, 1, 2, 1), Q72_3_ = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, NA, 3, 2, 4), 
    Q72_4_ = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, NA, 2, 3, 3), Q73_1_ = c(3, 
    3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4), Q73_2_ = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 
    4, 4, 3, 3), Q73_3_ = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3), Q73_4_ = c(2, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4), Q73_5_ = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    4, 3, 3, 4), Q73_6_ = c(3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3), Q73_7_ = c(3, 
    3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4), Q74 = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 3, 3), Q75_1_ = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), Q75_2_ = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Q75_3_ = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Q75_4_ = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), Q75_5_ = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), Q75_6_ = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), Q75_7_ = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Q75_8_ = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Q75_9_ = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), Q75_10_ = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), Q76_1_ = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, NA, 3, 2, 1), Q76_2_ = c(3, 
    3, 2, 3, 4, 3, NA, 3, 3, 4), Q76_3_ = c(4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 
    4, 2, 2, 4), Q77_1_ = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, NA, 3, 3, 4), Q77_2_ = c(2, 
    3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1), Q77_3_ = c(1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 
    NA, 2, 2, 1), Q78_1_ = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, NA, 2, 3, 1), 
    Q78_2_ = c(4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, NA, 3, 3, 4), Q78_3_ = c(4, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4), Q78_4_ = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 
    4, 2, 2, 2), Q78_5_ = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2), Q78_6_ = c(4, 
    3, 2, 4, 4, 3, NA, 3, 3, 4), Q78_7_ = c(3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 
    4, 3, 3, 4), Q79_1_ = c(3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3), Q79_2_ = c(2, 
    2, 2, 3, 4, 3, NA, 3, 3, 3), Q79_3_ = c(3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
    NA, 2, 2, 3), Q79_4_ = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, NA, 3, 3, 3), 
    Q79_5_ = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4), Q80_1_ = c(4, 4, 
    3, NA, 3, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4), Q80_2_ = c(1, 1, 1, NA, 4, NA, 
    NA, 3, NA, 1), Q80_3_ = c(1, 1, 1, NA, 2, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
    1), Q81_1_ = c(4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, NA, 1), Q81_2_ = c(3, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 2, NA, 3, 3, 1), Q81_3_ = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 
    NA, 1, NA, 1), Q81_4_ = c(3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, NA, 3, NA, 1), 
    Q81_5_ = c(4, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, NA, 1), Q81_6_ = c(4, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4), Q82_1_ = c(3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 
    3, 3, NA, 4), Q82_2_ = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, NA, 2, NA, 1), 
    Q82_3_ = c(4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Q82_4_ = c(4, 4, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Q82_5_ = c(2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA, 
    3, 3, 1), Q83_1_ = c(3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4), Q83_2_ = c(1, 
    2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1), Q83_3_ = c(2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 
    4, 3, 3, 3), Q83_4_ = c(4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3), Q83_5_ = c(4, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2), Q84_1_ = c(4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
    NA, 3, 3, 1), Q84_2_ = c(4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, NA, 3, 4, 4), 
    Q84_3_ = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, NA, 3, 2, 1), Q84_4_ = c(3, 
    3, 3, 2, 4, 3, NA, 3, 2, 1), Q84_5_ = c(3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 
    4, 3, 3, 1), Q85_1_ = c(2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, NA, 2, 1, 1), Q85_2_ = c(3, 
    2, 2, 2, 3, 1, NA, 2, 1, 1), Q85_3_ = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
    4, 3, 3, 4), Q85_4_ = c(3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, NA, 3, 3, 4), Q85_5_ = c(3, 
    3, 3, 2, 4, 3, NA, 3, 2, 4), Q86_1_ = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 
    NA, 2, 3, 1), Q86_2_ = c(4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1), Q86_3_ = c(2, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 3, NA, 3, 3, 4), Q86_4_ = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 
    NA, 3, 2, 1), Q86_5_ = c(3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4), Q86_6_ = c(2, 
    2, 3, 3, 2, 3, NA, 2, 2, 4), Q86_7_ = c(4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
    NA, 2, NA, 1), Q86_8_ = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3, NA, 1), 
    Q86_9_ = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, NA, 4), Q87_1_ = c(3, 
    3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4), Q87_2_ = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 
    3, 3, 2, 3), Q87_3_ = c(2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, NA, 3, 4, 2), Q87_4_ = c(3, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), Q88_1_ = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 2, 4), Q88_2_ = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA, 2), Q88_3_ = c(3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1), Q88_4_ = c(1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 2, 2), Q89_1_ = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2), Q89_2_ = c(1, 
    2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2), Q89_3_ = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 
    2, 3, 2, 3), Q89_4_ = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3), Q90 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would greatly appreciate any tips!

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide the data via `dput()` rather than just showing the sample data.

Comment: Hello Andrew, just updated the question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've interpreted your Question correctly.
Does this answer your question?

```
Num_Responses <- data %>% colSums(., na.rm = TRUE) %>% as.numeric()
Questions <- colnames(data)
tibble(Questions, Num_Responses) %>% write.csv(., file = "{{FILE PATH}}")
```

**Updated**
You could use something like this to get the frequency of each answer. Then you can use `write.csv()` to save the list iteratively.

```
lapply(data[, -1], function(x) as.data.frame(table(x)))
```

Comment: Thank you for giving some of your time. What I would like to get is the frequency for each answer to every variable. So for Q1 you would get something like that
   1    2    3    4    5 <NA> 
  784   49  619   81  133    8

Comment: @DavidPotrel Ah I see, I've updated my answer